# How to edit date cell and year cell in JFoenix date picker

Tags: css, javafx, jfoenix

Right now I have this grey hover effect for the date cell and year cell in my jfoenix date-picker. I would like to add a pointer and a different color whenever I hover over the two. Below you may see an image depicting the two. Would anybody know the css solution to this? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Documentation link: https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/master/jfoenix/src/main/resources/css/controls/jfx-date-picker.css

[image]

Comment: why do you delete a question and then post the exact same again? Please dont ... edit to improve the question, also ask the jfoenix crowd (if they have a forum) .. and be patient, less than a day without answer nor comment isn't sooo much :)

Comment: @kleopatra Thank you for the advice kleopatra. I uploaded the question at a questionable time last night so I wasn't sure if it got the right exposure.

Comment: if you edit a question, it shows up on top of the "active" list :) And time of day is different around the world so your question was not yet seen by all potential helpers :)

Comment: @kleopatra I see. I didn't know that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right. I did some digging myself and found the solution to my problem. So in case you do want to change the date cell and year cell in jfoenix date-picker. I would recommend the following. Please refer to the css code below:

```
.jfx-date-picker .date-picker-popup .calendar-grid .day-cell:hover,
.jfx-date-picker .data-picker-list-cell:hover {
    -fx-background-color: pink;
    -fx-cursor: hand;
}
```

This link was helpful:
https://jar-download.com/explore-java-source-code-detail.php?file=./javaSource/com.jfoenix/jfoenix/8.0.4/com/jfoenix/skins/JFXDatePickerContent.java&key=04bcc9b9067d674a50ae3f04ba744fe6